# CAN protocol for communication between EV and Charging equipment

Tags: automotive, can, charging, standard, electric-vehicle

I am trying to understand (and hopefully build) DC fast chargers (GB/T) for electric vehicles, specifically the communication between the Electric Vehicle Supply Equipment (EVSE) and the electric vehicle (EV). As per my understanding there is no standard that all OEMs follow in terms of connector types (GB/T, CHAdeMO, Tesla, CCS2). I was however wondering if there is a standard for CAN messages that need to be exchanged between EVSE and EV to determine charging voltage, power, fail-safe or fault conditions etc. So far I was not able to find any such document for GB/T kind of connectors. Does it mean that battery pack/BMS manufacturers and EVSE manufacturers have proprietary implementations? Would that not be good for cross-compatibility? Any leads on GB/T based implementations would be really helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching Chinese standards websites, it appears that the CAN protocol for communication between Electric Vehicle (EV) and Electric Vehicle Supply Equipment (EVSE) is documented in **GB/T 27930-2015** standard document. India follows similar approach and is documented in the standard **BIS 17017 Part 24**. I am unsure of the equivalent standard documents in European and Western countries.

Answer (score -1):

The only one I’m familiar with is Type 2, which uses an analogue voltage to indicate the permitted charging current, and DC signalling to switch AC power on and off.  There’s no CAN signalling in this plug type.

Comment: As the OP is asking about DC fast charging, your answer is not useful.